# Elechouse Voice Recognition v3 module not responding when I send command using Access port serial tool

Tags: serial

I have this challenge of receiving data when I send a command to voice recognition v3 module. The UART connections are okay, but when I send a command I don't receive a response on the terminal.

The prolific USB-TTL with drivers installed blinks when I send a command but still I get no response. Please help with debugging.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you have done.  E.g. show your code, circuit and the "commands" used.

Comment: I am using ACCESS PORT in trying to train the module as per the manual commands. But haven't achieved any success. Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 1):

The module can't communicate with Serial Monitor over a USB to TTL Serial adapter. It uses binary communication. Use Arduino, Arduino [library](https://github.com/elechouse/VoiceRecognitionV3) and one of the example sketches of the library to communicate with the VR module.

And read the [manual](https://www.elechouse.com/elechouse/images/product/VR3/VR3_manual.pdf).